# Convert MessageBag to simble single column array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

In laravel 6, i have below code

```
$messageBag = Validator::make([], [ 'x' => 'required|int' ])->getMessageBag(); // just for example
```

And need to convert `$messageBag` to an `array` with structure like this:

```
[
   "The x field is required.",
   "The x field is bla bla bla.",
   "The y field is something.",
]
```

structure of `$messageBag->toArray()` is:

```
[
   "x" => [
        "The x field is required.",
   ],
]
```

Comment: The reason why you probably wouldn't want to is in the off chance there's multiple fields that fail the same validation rule and they happen the use the same message

Comment: From my opinion, it's useless, pointless and wrong. But i have to do it.

Comment: try `Arr::flatten($messageBag->toArray())`

Comment: @apokryfos You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten an array using Laravel's built-in [helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers)

In your case you can use:

```php
$flatArray = Arr::flatten($messageBag->toArray())
```

As the document said:

> The Arr::flatten method flattens a multi-dimensional array into a single level array.